# CREATE TABLE with foreign key fails with ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

Whenever I try to reference the foreign key i get this error (missing keyword)
 Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE SP (
  S# CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  P# CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  QTY INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (S#,P#),
  FOREIGN KEY (S#) REFERENCE Supplier(S#) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: The `CHAR` columns should use the standard type, `VARCHAR2`, or perhaps even `INTEGER` (although probably the same mistake has been made with the parent table so that would need to change too). If you declare the FK as part of the column instead of separately at the end, you can omit the datatype and let it inherit from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- the syntax of the definition of your primary key is wrong; it should be `CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (S#, P#)`
- in the definition of the foreign key, keyword `REFERENCES` is missing the final `S`

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE SP (
  S# CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  P# CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  QTY INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT SP_PK PRIMARY KEY (S#, P#),
  FOREIGN KEY (S#) REFERENCES Supplier(S#) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d8f3c66221411357af3a56977b0f8a8d)**

Reminder: please note that the column referrenced by the primary key must be unique or a primary key in the referrenced table (ie column `S#` must be the primary key of table `Supplier` or have a `UNIQUE` constraint).